# How to pass the handle fetched from spy++ in sendmessage using c#?

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage, spy++

How to pass the handle which I got using spy++ tool in sendmessage?
ie. I want to pass this handle

> Handle Got from spy++ **00010540**

in this function

```
SendMessage(buttonHandle, WM_HSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_LINERIGHT, IntPtr.Zero);
```

where button handle is of type IntPtr.I want to substitute buttonhandle with the above value.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `new IntPtr(0x00010540)` should work.  For example like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, 
    UInt32 Msg, 
    IntPtr wParam, 
    IntPtr lParam);

SendMessage(
    new IntPtr(0x00010540), 
    0x0112,                 // WM_SYSCOMMAND
    new IntPtr(0xF020),     // SC_MINIMIZE
    IntPtr.Zero);
```